# Activiti compensation endTime is not logged

Tags: activiti

Although a **compensation** event started and all activity ended with success, compensation **endTime** is not logged.

version: Activiti 5.14

I've already created an issue:
https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ACT-2100

**Bpmn model is:**
[image: BPMN model]

**Process result is:**
[image: Process result]